# Is it possible to implement a modal with a list tag? Or would I have to use a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am making a personal portfolio website for myself.

```html
<footer>
  <ul class="icons">
   <li><a href="https://github.com" class="fa-github">GitHub</a></li>
  <li><a href="Resume.pdf" class="fa-file-text-o">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href = "#" class = "fa-phone"> Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
</footer>
```

In the code that is above, would it be possible to include a modal for the contact button? I have created a "contact.html" page and would like it to pop-up when the button is clicked rather than have a whole new page open up.

Or would I have to use the button tag instead of the  tag?

I am comfortable with using Bootstrap and can implement a modal with that framework if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this custom modal or bootstrap modal https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this model:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        modal
    </title>
    <style>
        body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

        /* The Modal (background) */
        .modal {
            display: none; /* Hidden by default */
            position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
            z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
            padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%; /* Full width */
            height: 100%; /* Full height */
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
            background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
        }

        /* Modal Content */
        .modal-content {
            background-color: #fefefe;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #888;
            width: 80%;
        }

        /* The Close Button */
        .close {
            color: #aaaaaa;
            float: right;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .close:hover,
        .close:focus {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="icons">
        <li><a href="https://github.com" class="fa-github">GitHub</a></li>
        <li><a href="Resume.pdf" class="fa-file-text-o">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href = "#" class = "fa-phone" id="contact"> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script>
                    // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var contact = document.getElementById("contact");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        contact.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```